# Adding dynamic effects using any javascript IDE

Tags: javascript

Is there any IDE which allows to add dynamic effects to web page elements without actually writing javascript code? It could use some third party javascript library/framework such as jQuery/Mochi etc.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely there is such IDE that will provide WYSIWYG interface for you to add jQuery/Mochi/Prototype... effects to your HTML. Other than that - all modern IDE's do have jquery support: netbeans, phpstorm, eclipse, aptana.

So the answer (likely) is: no, you'll have to read jquery documentation a bit (it's easy to understand and learn, there are multiple tutorials on jquery websites) to write a code for these "dynamic effects"